# Is casting a function [X, Y] X => Y to X => () safe as long as I ignore the returned value?

Tags: scala, jvm-bytecode

```
val f = { x :Int => x }
val g = f.asInstanceOf[Int, Unit] 
g(1) //works
```

How brittle is the above code? It works currently, but of course it is not a part of language specification. For this reason, it is of course possible, that one day it will not; my question is how likely it would be, understood in the sense of sensible alternatives for the compiler. I do not know bytecode well, but I could easily imaging it breaking by trying to put an `Int` into a `Unit` register. On the other hand, this working can actually be an undocumented consequence of documented specification
of the Scala compiler and Java bytecode itself.

My motivation lies primarly in `@specialized` code. For example, `Iterable` contains the following method:

```
trait Iterable[E] /* ... */
    def foreach[T](f :E => T) :Unit
```

This signature was probably chosen to allow passing any function of `E` one might have as an argument.
In practice though, it will almost always be a lambda/method value. The problem with the above method
is that it would require specializing on both `E` and `T`, leading to a square number of method variants, which should be avoided. Not specializing on `T` is pointless, because scalac doesn't emit `@specialized` subclasses for subsets of type parameters: if any of the `@specialized` parameters receive a reference (or a non-specialized) type as the argument, the whole object will be an instance of the erased superclass. Similarly, there is no `apply(Int):Object` method - if the return type is erased, then the erased `apply(Object):Object` will be called, resulting in boxing. So, it would be much more desirable in this case to have

```scala
def foreach(f :E => Unit) :Unit
```

Introducing such a method (with a different name) and using it as the delegate target of the regular `foreach` is possible and doesn't result in any boxing, at least as long as the created lambda doesn't have a reference type as its return type.

Comment: I am a bit lost, the motive for this question is that you want to add your own **Iterable** which is specialized?

Comment: My own collection, in this example, yes. And have a linear number, not n^2, of specialized methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the context.

Most of the time Scala will compile code so that function returning `Unit` will be called as JVM's `void` (no returned result) or it will treat it as returning `scala.Unit`'s only value which can be discarded. As long as JVM won't try to call anything on this returned value it will only assume that it is some `java.lang.Object` that should be checked for `scala.Unit` if used for anything, which could never happen.

But it doesn't mean it's impossible.

```
val f: Int => Int = _ * 2
val g: Unit => Int = _ => 10
(f.asInstanceOf[Int => Unit] andThen g)(10)
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class scala.runtime.BoxedUnit (java.lang.Integer is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; scala.runtime.BoxedUnit is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
  scala.Function1.$anonfun$andThen$1(Function1.scala:85)
  scala.Function1.apply$mcII$sp(Function1.scala:69)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd27$.<clinit>(cmd27.sc:1)
```

As long as you call it in your own code, that you have full control, always know the context, test, etc it should be fine.

Which IMHO is a bad assumption for basically every library in the world or any codebase that would be maintained more than one week.

```
f.andThen(_ => ())
```

would always be safer and I would have to have some really good reasons to use optimization like `.asInstanceOf` and risk some funny errors in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`asInstanceOf` is an inherently unsafe universal escape hatch. When you use it, you're really telling the type checker to blindly trust you.

In general, when you write `x.asInstanceOf[Y]`, you're making a promise to the compiler that the value `x` is really of type `Y`.

This is only ever guaranteed to work if `x` really is of type `Y`. If not, the compiler will do some special handling if `x` is known statically to be a primitive type, or `null`. Then one of two things will happen:

- Runtime will see through your lies and throw a `ClassCastException`.
- You get away with your lies and possibly other things break down the line.

In your example, f is of type `Int => Int`, which is clearly not a subtype of `Int => Unit`. In other words: you're lying to the compiler, and all guarantees are void.

The moral of this story is: You should never rely on implementation details for correctness, and you should always treat `asInstanceOf` as unsafe.

As Mateusz wrote, `f.andThen(_ => ())` or equivalently `{ x => {f(x); ()}}` is the only correct way to convert some `A => B` to `A => Unit`.

You should also note that while it is possible to generate specialized methods that take specialized functions as arguments, `(x => x).asInstanceOf[Int => Unit]` will always return an unspecialized `Function1[Int,Unit]`, not a specialized type, so this won't help you at all with performance.